# Java Exception Classes

Tags: java, exception

I am new to Java and I was looking at exception handling. When we catch java exceptions, we declare and use an `Object` of the `Exception` class without initializing it, i.e.

```
catch(NullPointerException e)
    e.printStackTrace();
```

So my question is, how are we able to use object reference e without instantiating it?

Comment: Hint: The exception object you are catching *was* instantiated within the block that threw the exception to begin with.

Comment: The same applies to method parameters. They are constructed elsewhere and sent to the method. No different with exceptions, just a different mechanism.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are well instantiated:

```
void example() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("message");
}      // ^^^

void demonstration() {
    try {
       example();
    } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This very simple example should be pretty self explanatory...

Answer (score 1):

The exception is (often) instantiated when the error occurs with a `throw` statement. For example,

```
throw new NullPointerException();
```

(Note that this is just an example. NPEs are not usually explicitly thrown in your own code.)

The `catch` clause is similar to a function that declares a parameter. Consider the function

```
void func(String s) {
    // ...
}
```

`func` does not instantiate the `s`. The `String` is created somewhere else and passed to the function. In the same way, we create an exception with `throw` and it is "passed" to the `catch` clause kind of like a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, reference `e` in `catch(NullPointerException e)` is for the possible exception thrown in code using `throw new NullPointerException("some error message");`

Answer (score 0):

The exception is instantiated. It happens internally in the class that can potentially throw an exception. For your information, the keyword throw is responsible to create and throw the exception. Your catch method will catch the exception. You can also implement your own exceptions using this keyword.